# The secured image was created using a trial version of CliSecure and can not run on this machine. - Why I'm getting this message?

Tags: windows-7

> The secured image was created using a trial version of CliSecure and
>   can not run on this machine.

Why I'm getting this message?

I'm on Windows 7 - 64bit Home premium

Answer (score 2):

The .NET program you are trying to run was protected using CliSecure against decompilation; however, a trial version of [CliSecure](http://secureteam.net/) (Now named "Agile.Net") was used, which has a restriction that protected programs may not be run on any other computer.